# jQuery hide box

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem is quite simple. When I click on visible image all the boxes which were appeared should dissapear and on active field it should appear. The thing is when I click on the same field twice the box does not dissapear.

I hope my code will explain more what I want to do.
Code:

**jquery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var img = $('.users_table tr .user_gear').find('img');
        //var dropdown = $('.users_table tr .user_gear').next('.user_arrow_box');

        if((img).is(':visible') == true){
            img.click(function(){
                var all = $('.users_table tr .user_gear').find('.user_arrow_box');
                var a = $(this).parent().find('.user_arrow_box');
                a.toggle(function() {
                    all.removeClass('active');
                    a.addClass('active');
                }, function() {
                    a.removeClass('active');
                });

                return false;
            });
        }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle exemple ?

Comment: I think you need the if(...visible...) statement inside the img.click event.
Otherwise, you will not even register the click event, if the image is not visible on page load

Comment: Why do you need the `visible` statement at all? If the image isn't visible, it won't/can't be clicked. It's also wise to **not** name variables the same as standard tags... I would suggest not using `img` as a variable name.

Comment: Because if I want to click the image it has to be visible here :). Because in css I have img { visibility: hidden; } and I have other jquery statement which checks if I hover the table tr wheter image becomes visible :)

Comment: You miss my point... *how would you click an image that **isn't** visible*?

Comment: It's a little more complicated to clarify the situation it just has to be like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
img.click(function(){
                var all = $('.users_table tr .user_gear').find('.user_arrow_box');
                var a = $(this).parent().find('.user_arrow_box');
                    all.not($(a)).removeClass('active');
                    a.toggleClass('active');
                return false;
            });
```

Comment: I don't want to make all the boxes activated. I need to make only that I clicked. It's something similar to active menu link. But the thing is that if I click on the same image twice 

first time: the box should appear
second time: the box should dissapear

additionaly:
 if I click on different box the other one should dissapear. :)